# How to use create in selectize js for multiple select element

Tags: javascript, html, selectize.js

I'm trying to use `<select multiple="multiple"></select>` with selectize.js. I did it like this:

index.html

`<select multiple="multiple" id="to"></select>`

script

```
$('#to').selectize({
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    persist: false,
    create: function(input){
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    },
    valueField: 'email',
    labelField: 'email',
    searchField: ['email'],
    options: JSON.parse('{{ $email }}'),
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape){
            return '<div>' + 
                (item.email ? '<code>' + escape(item.email) + '</code>' : '') +
                '</div>';
        },
        option: function(item, escape){
            var caption = item.email ? item.email : null;

            return '<div>' +
                (caption ? '<span class="text-primary">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
                '</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

It is working fine, but what I want is to also allow the user to add more item. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

add maxItems: number-of-options as per the documentation https://selectize.dev/docs.html